# Code executing enter without executing a command to click

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Not sure what I have done wrong but when I run the code it runs as i want it to but when the text from the text file is inputted it executes an enter press

```
import os
from time import sleep
from selenium import webdriver

chrome_path = (r"C:\Users\George\Desktop\case script\romowa\Drivers\chromedriver.exe")
text_file1 = open(r"C:\Users\George\Desktop\case script\romowa\acounts\name.txt", "r")
x = 0 #count up
a=0

while True:
    browser = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_path)
    browser.implicitly_wait(30)
    browser.get('http://www.google.com')
    x = x+1
    name = text_file1.readlines(x)
    browser.find_element_by_name("q").send_keys(name)
    sleep(1)
    browser.quit()
    a = a +1
    sleep(1)
```

Comment: It might be happening because of the new line character "\r\n" at the end of the text that you are reading from file. You can verify this by trying two different values for name lets say "abc" and "abc \r\n" instead of reading from file.

Comment: @Nish26 Hey, thank you for your reply unfortunately this hasn't work any other suggestions would be greatly appreciated as i am still racking my brain about this haha.

Thanks, George

Answer (score 0):

I tried with C# bindings for chrome browser  :

1. Following snippet of code will simply set the value in search box

   ```
   IWebElement searchInput = webDriver.FindElement(By.Name("q"));
   searchInput.SendKeys("Hello");
   ```
2. Following snippet of code will set the value in search box and perform a search as well

   ```
   IWebElement searchInput = webDriver.FindElement(By.Name("q"));
   searchInput.SendKeys($"Hello {Environment.NewLine}");
   ```

   Notice the Environment.NewLine in above code which is equivalent to \n.

From python documentation for [readline()](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects)

> f.readline() reads a single line from the file; a newline character
>   (\n) is left at the end of the string, and is only omitted on the last
>   line of the file if the file doesn’t end in a newline. This makes the
>   return value unambiguous; if f.readline() returns an empty string, the
>   end of the file has been reached, while a blank line is represented by
>   '\n', a string containing only a single newline.

For  [readlines()](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/file_readlines.htm)

> readlines() reads until EOF using readline() and returns a list
>   containing the lines

It is clearly documented that a newline character \n is left at the end of string. As a result of this when sendkeys is trying to write the line it will also cause \n to be send simulating a search.

I would request you to try following and observe results :

1. hardcoded value

   ```
   name = "Hello"
   browser.find_element_by_name("q").send_keys(name)
   ```
2. single line from file using readline() instead of readlines(). Make sure you create a new file where you type "Hello" and save it without hitting enter key to add new line.

   ```
   name = text_file1.readline(x)
   browser.find_element_by_name("q").send_keys(name)
   ```

This should clear things.